# Display Multiselect bootstrap drop-down value in div with checkbox options

Tags: python, jquery, django, select, bootstrap-4

I have a multiselect bootstrap drowdown. I want to display the selected values from a drop-down in a separate div as rows with multiple checkboxes to select. How I can proceed for this? Like I have selected 3 items(I1,I2,I3) from dropdown then i should display all the three items as rows with 5 checkboxes to select in each row. The count of checkbox is fixed. This div should not be available on page load and clearing the values of dropdown. Any idea would help.Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ReverendPete Please find the JSFiddle link, http://jsfiddle.net/suf48dwp/, I want to add the selected options into the table's tbody in each row and checkboxes in each row for all td's.

Comment: Were you able to finish this?

Comment: @JerdineSabio I have tried this code in JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/k7nL3s2z/ . Please let me know if there is any better approach. I need to pass this data(Selected dropdown value with selected checkbox for that row) to backend. Also, the next step would be if Mustard is selected then I need to prefill A,B and C checkboxes already and option to check the rest of the boxes(Will get the list of 
 list of checkboxes to prefill from backend). Thanks!